# How to get the return values of function with arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a python exercise that requires getting the string return values of function. Here is the sample code that is related to the one I'm currently working on.

```
def main():
    x = 'the quick'
    y = 'brown fox'
    return x, y

def function1(x, y):
    if x == 'the quick' and y == 'brown fox':
        return 'jump'
    else:
        return 'lazy'

def function2():
    if a == 'jump':
        print('good boy')
    else:
        print('bad boy')

function2(*function1(*main()))
```

I'm getting positional argument error. How to return the string properly for other function?

Comment: Can you paste the error here, I got a different error when I ran your code (i got `TypeError: function2() takes no arguments (4 given)`).

Comment: Good question... However, I would recommend using decorators instead.

Comment: "TypeError: function2() takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you have to specify parameters for function2: I guess you want to define function2 in this way:

```
    def function2(a):
        if a == 'jump':
        print('good boy')
    else:
        print('bad boy')
```

And you may want funtion2 output 'good boy', In this way,  you could try:

```
function2(function1(*main()))
```

Which will give the output as you want.

Comment: I forgot to put a parameter and I put an asterisk in function1 which iterates the word instead. Thanks @Lei_Bai

Answer (score 6):

You have not specified that `Function2()` takes any arguments.

I got your code to run by specifying four function arguments (while only using one):

```
def main():
    x = 'the quick'
    y = 'brown fox'
    return x, y

def function1(x, y):
    if x == 'the quick' and y == 'brown fox':
        return 'jump'
    else:
        return 'lazy'

def function2(a, b, c, d):
    if a == 'jump':
        print('good boy')
    else:
        print('bad boy')

function2(*function1(*main()))
```

This returns:

```
bad boy
```

Comment: Maybe `*args` and `args[0] == 'jump'` would be more in the spirit of splatting the return value of function1 into function2? But then being explicit about 4 arguments probably demonstrates what' going on more clearly, so maybe it's better this way.

Comment: This also made sense, it shows what happens to returned value. I mistakenly put an asterisk to function1 that splits the returned value.